# Loading a module's import table

Tags: c++, windows, import, portable-executable

Is there a easy way to load a module's import table (the modules it imports itself) or I have to parse its PE header myself?
I'm using C++ on windows.

Comment: I did this a couple years ago. Check this link: [ImageNtHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx "MSDN")